# Errors in OpenCL kernel code at runtime

Tags: windows, visual-studio, compiler-errors, runtime-error, opencl

I am new to Visual Studio and I am using it to write a simple parallel sorting program using OpenCL.
When I run it, I get a line before my output (i.e. from before I receive and print the result buffer) saying "5 Errors Generated.".
I assume this is telling me that I have errors in my kernel file, and if I deliberately write errors in my kernel file that number increases.

I would really like to know what those errors are so I can correct my program. Being unfamiliar with VS I simply cannot find them listed anywhere. 
Does anyone know where I can find what errors are being generated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [clGetProgramBuidlInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetProgramBuildInfo.html) asking for the CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG in order to get the runtime errors of the compiler.

```
char result[4096];
size_t size;
clGetProgramBuildInfo( program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(result), result, &size);
printf("%s\n", result);
```